# AWS s3 bucket connection to Node js server

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, fetch-api, secret-key

I am trying to access my AWS service but my access key and secret access key credentials seem not to be set. How do I troubleshoot this issue as both keys are up and available in my AWS?

I have set all policies and access to my s3 resource to 'public', I have generated and downloaded the  'rootkey.csv' file containing both access keys and added a 'env' file to the appropriate directory where my project work is. I am expecting a link to my AWS resource, but on trying to connect via Node js, the test script I wrote in trying to ascertain connection via access keys tell me my access keys are not set.

Comment: Suggest you read the documentation for [configuring the Node.js SDK](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v3/developer-guide/configuring-the-jssdk.html).